# How to keep levels when using factor variables in a new dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, factors, levels

I expect that this is a basic question; however, I looked all the suggested posts and searched myself and I couldn't find the answer.  I just to know why if I create a new dataframe based on factor variables from an existing one, I appear to lose the levels.  Why does it happen and how can I keep the levels with a factor variable?  Here's a reproducible example to demonstrate:

```
data(iris)
str(iris) # Species variable is of the class factor
iris.lm <- lm(Petal.Width ~ Species, iris) # Fit a simple model
summary(iris.lm) # Levels are displayed

# Now I make a new dataframe to do some fit quality checks
iris.plots <- as.data.frame(cbind(iris$Species, iris$Petal.Width, fitted(iris.lm),residuals(iris.lm)))
names(iris.plots) <- c("Species", "Observed", "Predicted", "Residuals")

# In the scatter plot to view Residuals by predictor (Species, of factor class), I have not maintained the levels.
plot(x = iris.plots$Species, y = iris.plots$Residuals)
head(iris.plots) # Confirming that I "lost" the levels
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `cbind` on numeric vectors (even if one of them is factor), as an output you receive matrix, without any information of levels. To prevent it, you can, for example, pass column of `iris$Species` as data frame:

```
iris.plots <- cbind(as.data.frame(iris$Species), iris$Petal.Width, fitted(iris.lm),residuals(iris.lm))
```

Now, `cbind` recognizes first column being `data.frame` and uses version of method for data frames, which preserves levels.